# Running lengthy shutdown script on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shutdown, upstart

I need to perform some cleanup work before shutdown that will take 15 to 150 seconds on Kununtu 14.10.

The cleanup action should be start after all network services like sshd, ftpd, samba etc. are stopped and before any local file systems are unmounted.

I tried to create a upstart job with "stop on runlevel [!2345]" but had no success. Sometimes the script starts executing but does not run to completion. Mostly the script is not started at all.

My goal is that my script delays the power off (and unmount) until the script completes.
Any advice how to implement (and install) this?